# problem in array of button

Tags: android

I am creating a dynamic array of buttons, but i am getting Nullpointer Exception. Why?
My sample code is:

```
 Button addAsFriend[];
 for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
 {
    addAsFriend[i]=new Button(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn´t initialized your array, try this:

```
Button addAsFriend[] = new Button[c.getCount()];
 for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
 {
    addAsFriend[i] = new Button(this);
 }
```

Comment: how can i implement the click events for each button in this array

Answer (score 0):

You aren't initializing the array itself, only the elements inside? See line 2:

```
Button addAsFriend[];
addAsFriend = new Button[c.GetCount()];
    for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
           addAsFriend[i]=new Button(this);
        }
```

Edit: Pretty silly of me to delete this.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you out:

```
Button[] b = new Button[9];
b[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
b[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
b[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
b[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
b[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
b[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
b[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
b[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
```